# Using GTK+, how do I add a Label to a Box after it's created?

Tags: gtk, rust

Here's some code I've been working on (in Rust, using the excellent gtk-rs bindings):

```
use gtk;
use gtk::prelude::*;

struct LabelViewer {
    pub container: gtk::ScrolledWindow,
    layout: gtk::Box,
    fields: Vec<gtk::Label>,
}
impl LabelViewer {  
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let container = gtk::ScrolledWindow::new(None, None);
        let layout = gtk::Box::new(gtk::Orientation::Vertical, 5);
        container.add(&layout);
        LabelViewer {
            container: container,
            layout: layout,
            fields: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
    pub fn set_labels(&mut self, labels: &[String]) {
        for label in self.fields.drain(..) {
            self.layout.remove(&label);
        }
        for label in labels.iter().map(|l| gtk::Label::new(Some(l))) {
            self.layout.pack_start(&label, false, false, 0);
            self.fields.push(label);
        }
    }
}
```

When I create a `LabelViewer` and add its container to my Window, I see the border of the ScrolledWindow, indicating that it is indeed being added. However, when I call `set_labels`, no labels are actually rendered.

I have some experience with Swing (from Java), but this is my first time using GTK. Based on my past experience I tried invalidating the container with `queue_draw`, after calling `set_labels`, but that didn't have any effect. It may not be relevant, but I call `set_labels` *before* `gtk::main()`.

Comment: Is `set_labels()` called *after* `window.show_all()`?

Comment: Yes, it is. That's why I considered calling `queue_draw` to invalidate the widget - it had already been validated by the the `show_all()` call.

Comment: It's not that the labels are not drawn, it's that all new widgets are invisible initially. Add `label.show()` to your `set_labels()` for loop (or `self.layout.show_all()` below it) and you should see your labels.

Comment: That was it! In retrospect it makes sense for newly created things to be invisible, but it's a bit unintuitive at first. Could you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newly created GtkWidgets are initially hidden. You need to call `show()` or `show_all()` on them to make them visible (the latter will recursively show a container's children). This means you have to issue that call yourself if you add widgets after you call `show_all()` on a window. In your case, you can either call `show()` individually for each label or call `show_all()` on `self.layout` after adding all the labels.